# IFormFile passing null value to Action in asp.netcore RazorPage 6.0 using vs2022

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0, iformfile

i created a dotnetCore6.0 MVC RazorePage solution using VisualStudio2022 ,
i have a page that give a excel file and will be insert into database ,
unfortinantly whenever trying to send the file, it is NULL in the action !
also my httpcontext.Request.Form Has a Error!
here is my cshtml :

```
<div class = "card">
    <div class="card-header"> Upload Products Excel File   </div>
    <div class="card-body" >
        <form asp-action="BulkInsert"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
            <div class="form-group" >
                <lable> Excel File </lable>
                <input name="excelFile" id="excelFile" type="file" accept=".xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn-primary btn-success" >
                    Send File
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the cs method

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BulkInsert(IFormFile excelFile)
    {
        // First Add Package  'dotnet add package ExcelDataReader' 
        // then using MemoryStream to read Excel data

        var formFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
        var aa = HttpContext;
        List<ProductViewModel> products = new List<ProductViewModel>();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            excelFile.CopyTo(ms);
            bool firstRow = true;

            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(ms))
            {
                do
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (firstRow)// Breakes First Row
                        {
                            firstRow = false;
                            continue;

                        }
                        var product = new ProductViewModel()
                        {
                            ProductName = reader[0].ToString(),
                            CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]),
                            SupplierID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]),
                            UnitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(reader[3]),
                        };
                        products.Add(product);
                    }
                    
                } 
                while(reader.NextResult());
            }

        }
        return View(nameof(Index));
    }

}
```

Comment: "dotnetCore6.0 MVC RazorePage solution" What's project template do you use ? I use the MVC template to test your code and get the file , like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeIXU.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's really funny i implemented this code at my workplace and forgot to put them to github !
now i implementing the project at home again and everything works exactly correct !!!!!!
think i installed a wrong Package at workplace .
here is the package that i instaled at home.

ExcelDataReader v3.6.0

instaled more than 63.3M

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `method="post"` in your form element:

`<form asp-action="BulkInsert"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">`

Comment: tested it before too ! not worked!

Comment: nope! test it before...

Answer (score 0):

Two important points about your code:

1-Correct the spelling of lable to label.

2-Use type="submit" in the button to specify the submit type.

Comment: oops! not worked! :( TNX a lot for ur Help DUDE

Answer (score 0):

Use **Model** to pass data. so simply create a model and use this in view page

View.cshtml

```
<Input type="file" asp-for="File">
```

And also use **input type submit** to submit a form.

Model.cs

```
Public class Model{
    Public IFormFile File {get; set;}
}
```

And in controller put model as parameter

Controller.cs

```
Public Action (Model model){
  // you get file here using model.File
}
```

Try this way....

Comment: tested both of way ! it's null Still !